# Symfony redirect to a part of page

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-3.4

I have a symfony page composed of 3 parts  ( and i'm using tags to display each part) by navigation menu here is the navigation menu.

```
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs centered">
 <li class="active">
 <a href="#fiche_patient" data-toggle="tab"> {{ 'fiche_pharmacie'|trans }}</a> 
 </li>
 <li>
 <a href="#my_team2" data-toggle="tab"> {{ 'Mon équipe'|trans }} </a>
 </li>
 <li>
 <a href="#config" data-toggle="tab"> {{ 'Configuration_automate'|trans }}</a> 
 </li>
 {#  <li>
 <a href="#tab_3" data-toggle="tab"> {{ 'Services'|trans }} </a>
 </li> #}
 </ul>
```

After that i call 3 twig pages to display each page content.

```
 <div class="tab-pane" id="fiche_patient">
 {{ include(':prof/Entreprise:indexdetails.html.twig') }}
 </div>
 <div class="tab-pane" id="my_team2">
 {{ include(':prof/Entreprise:my-team.html.twig') }}
 </div>
 <div class="tab-pane" id="config">
 {{ include(':prof/Entreprise:config.html.twig') }}
 </div>
```

My probleme is after submit i would like to display config.html.twig page.

In my controler i tried :

```
  return $this->redirect($this-> generateUrl('entreprise_index'.'#config'));
```

but it doesn't work
Any one of you have an idea ?

Comment: What error are you getting from symfony when trying to redirect ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax for what you are trying to do there is:

```
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('entreprise_index').'#config');
```

Comment: the correct syntax is : return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('entreprise_index').'#config');

Comment: right you are, thanks @Marooweb. Removed the extra parenthesis there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use redirectToRoute()

```
$yourRouteParams = array('param1'=>1);
return $this->redirectToRoute('entreprise_index', $yourRouteParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send the tab name as a parameter to twig. And, in the template, set the active tab according to that parameter.